# How to simplify / optimize this jQuery

Tags: jquery, query-optimization

Im new to this but, there has to be a better way of writing this.

Three similar functions, can they be combined with a comma or something.

```
$('#open-sidebar').click(function(){
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});
$('#close-sidebar').click(function(){
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});

$("#top").bind("swiperight", function (e) {
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});
$("#content").bind("swiperight", function (e) {
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});
$("#top").bind("swipeleft", function (e) {
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});

$("#content").bind("swipeleft", function (e) {
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});
$("#navigation").bind("swipeleft", function (e) {
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});
```

Thank you

Comment: You should ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var $body = $(document.body);

function toggleBody () {
    $body.toggleClass("menu-active");
    return false;
}

$('#open-sidebar, #close-sidebar').click(toggleBody);
$('#top, #content').bind('swiperight swipeleft', toggleBody);
$('#navigation').bind('swipeleft', toggleBody);
```

Comment: And whoever upvoted that comment, why didn't they upvote the answer?  O_o

Comment: Because it doesn't deserve an upvote in my opinion. Sure, it answers the question, but i dont' think this question belongs here in the first place.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It could be optimized further by combining all the events into a single binding, but that's a very tiny optimization anyway. To be clear, i'm not the dv, i'm the uv. I don't think you should be downvoted for trying to help and actually doing that successfully.

Comment: @KevinB - Not following you. AFAIK, this is the most efficient way to do it with the least amount of code. But I guess you know best. Would you mind adding your own answer?

Comment: No, because this question doesn't deserve an answer.

Comment: @TacoFiesta - Trying to find out the same. Let me know when you do find out why :)

Answer (score 0):

With this syntax

```
$("#navigation, #content, ... ").bind("swipeleft", function (e) {
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});
```

And you need one for click also

```
$('#close-sidebar, #id2, #id3, ....').click(function(){
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: AH!, This is what i was looking for.I was doing it wrong like this...
    $("#navigation", "#content", "#top")...

Thanks everyone, i didn't test the others

Comment: @TacoFiesta Now see if you asked your question with THAT information your question would have been more on topic.